# Install wordpress plugin in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, plugins, google-cloud-platform

I have a site with wordpress in Google Cloud Platform, But I don't know, how I can to install a wordpress plugin if I can use FTP. Which are the credentials or others ways to do.

Comment: I just went through that. I found this very helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDcjM7BySo0

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Before posting, you are expected to have ***researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself***. There are lots of resources out there to help. Stack Overflow is not the place to ask for general help, but if you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a clear outline and a summary of what you have tried.